# Android copy error from asset

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, assets

I am trying to make an application in android, by using the pre-created database. 
I create the data file and keep it in `asset` folder, then i when the application run, it will copy to the `/data/data/package name/databases/data`
The problem is that when i run with `android 2.2` , it copy correctly. but when i run from `android 2.3.3` over, it doesn't copy the database and also not show any errors.
Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try {
     despath="/data/data/" + getPackageName()+"/databases/data";
    File f=new File(despath);
    if(!f.exists())
   {

        CopyDB( getBaseContext().getAssets().open("data"),new FileOutputStream(despath));
    }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void CopyDB(InputStream inputstream, OutputStream outputstream) throws IOException
{
    byte[] buffer=new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while((length=inputstream.read(buffer))>0)
    {
        outputstream.write(buffer,0,length);
    }
    inputstream.close();
    outputstream.close();
}   

}
```

Comment: Follow this tutorial http://v4all123.blogspot.in/2013/03/sqlite-databases-with-external-db.html

Comment: Regardless if it is the cause of your problem or not, you should not be **assuming** what the database path is; discover it at runtime using the provided APIs.